# Class Diagram OOP

Tags: oop, class-diagram

If two classes are associated regularly, do they need to contain each other's objects as attributes? For example, a Post class and a Comment class on a social media platform. Should the Post class contain an array of comment objects as an attribute? And should the Comment class contain a post object as an attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common mistake of redundant information. It does not need to be shown in the class diagram as a field because it is derived from the association. 
This is a class diagram that covers what you have mentioned in its simplest form.
[image]

As you can see, objects for each class do not need to be added as fields.

Comment: Thank you, good to know. Regarding the actual implementation of the association, would my suggestion of including an array of comment objects in the post class and a post object in the comment class be appropriate?

Comment: I think as an initial implementation it is a good idea. But if you see that there is a lot of functionality in some of the classes, then you may need to think differently.

Comment: Would it be better to include the id attributes rather than the actual objects? Like to have an array of (comment_id : int ) in Post and (post_id: int) in Comment?

Comment: I consider that having the actual object as attribute is a better solution because through it you will be able to access the fields and methods of this class. If you have the id as you say, then you will not have direct access to the fields and methods of the class, as they will stop to be directly related to each other.

Comment: Additionally, you may want to add an extension to the software or even now, e.g. for each comment on the post display the time that the comment was made. If you have declared the actual objects as fields, then accessing the "time" field of the Comment class is easy. But if you only had the comment id as a field, then things would be more complicated to get the time. The goal is generally to make things as simple and as scalable as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your help, makes perfect sense.